# do QueueMessagingTemplate run async or sync in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-sqs

Now I use QueueMessagingTemplate to consume message in SQS, and I observe `private final AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs` in the class `QueueMessagingTemplate`. Does `AmazonSQSAsync` run async or sync when I use a method in this class (for example I use `receive`)?

Answer (score 1):

`AmazonSQSAsync` according to the AWS Java SDK:

> Interface for accessing Amazon SQS asynchronously. Each asynchronous method will return a Java Future object representing the asynchronous operation; overloads which accept an AsyncHandler can be used to receive notification when an asynchronous operation completes.

So it will run sync but return a future object.

Comment: Hi @NamHuỳnhTrungBùi, if you find the answer helpful, you can mark it as the answer to help other developers that will have the same question in the future.

Comment: agree with this